# Flash Apps with Flash Builder?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I've just started with Flash and my project requires me to develop Flash apps using Actionscript int Flash Builder. What could be a good resource to start with this except for Adobe's online documentation? I still can't find a decent ebook for this. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

These links might help you:

http://www.lynda.com/Flex-4-tutorials/flex-4-essential-training/61161-2.html

http://active.tutsplus.com/articles/reviews/flash-builder-for-as3-developers/

Comment: Pranav Hosangadi: thanks, many more questions are also here whose grammer is not corrected please go through them also.